# Pegar dados de uma url externa pelo codigo fonte da pagina

Tags: php, javascript, html

Ola preciso pegar a latitude , e longitude que esta em uma url

No codigo fonte da url,  tem uma tabela segue abaixo, o que eu preciso é desses valores -22.96555, -43.17969 que esta na (TD 4 da tabela)  preciso dela em uma variavel php alguém poderia me ajudar

```html
<table id="tabela-lista" class="cyber tabela-lista">
 
 <tr id="TStr0" class="">
  <td><a id="nota_0" href="javascript:Abrir('../posicoes/posicoes_nota.php?posicao=1251853304', '_blank', 500, 300);void(0);"><img src="../img/novo.png" height='32px' widht='32px'\></a></td>
  <td>12/04/2017 10:21:57</td>
  <td>12/04/2017 10:22:09</td>
  <td>-22.96555, -43.17969</td>
  <td>0,00</td>
  <td>Temporizado</td>
  <td>Sim</td>
  <td>Ligada</td>
  <td>Satélite</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 
</table>
```

Comment: Essa tabela é gerada de forma dinâmica ou tem como personalizá-la colocando uma class na td por exemplo?

Comment: No caso não tenho acesso ao código fonte no caso ela e gerada  TStr0 ,TStr1 , TStr2 mais gostaria de pegar apenas da ultima posicao que e zero

Comment: O que seria está URL que você cita? É uma página externa da qual você quer extrair as informações ou é uma página da sua aplicação mesmo?

Comment: Uma pagina externa

Comment: E ela exige autenticação, correto? Se sim, já adianto para editar a sua pergunta e colocar todas essas informações - que são cruciais para a solução do problema.

Comment: Você precisará das funções `curl` para pegar o código HTML da página, efetuando a devida autenticação. Depois, com a classe do PHP `DOMDocument` você poderá tratar o HTML, buscando pela linha da tabela desejada através do método `getElementById("TStr0")` (do PHP, tem nada de JS aqui), após buscar pela quarta coluna deste elemento e extrair seu conteúdo.

Comment: Entendi mais nao sei como fazer isso

Comment: Sei o basico de php

Comment: Agora já sabe por onde começar a estudar.

Comment: Kkk pois é preciso estudar funcao cur isso primeiro para autenticar a pagina?

Comment: Entendi, mas confesso que a pergunta estava bem ambígua, para o seu caso é normal utilizar curl https://imasters.com.br/artigo/4140/php/usando-a-biblioteca-curl-do-php?trace=1519021197&source=single